# No visualizo información en navegador [Angular7]

Tags: api, typescript, angular7

mi problema es el siguiente.

Tengo mi aplicación que me regresa la información desde mi REST API a mi aplicación en angular y el problema surge al momento de querer mostrar esa información en el navegador, lo cual no pasa no muestra nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la vista es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me retorna la siguiente informacion en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Enseguida el codigo de mi vista:

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { GamesService } from '../../services/games.service';
import { Game } from '../../models/Game';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-list',
  templateUrl: './game-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-list.component.css']
})
export class GameListComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('class') classes = 'row';
  game: any = [];
  constructor(private gamesService: GamesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGames();
  }
  getGames() {
    this.gamesService.getGames()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.game = res;
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}
```

El codigo de mi servicio:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Game } from '../models/Game';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GamesService {
  API_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getGames() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/games`);
  }
}
```

Y la ruta me retorna la misma información, me gustaría saber cual es el error que estoy cometiendo.

De antemano muchas gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En le GameListComponent tienes la variable 'game' y en el for 'games', creo que la 's' es la raíz de todos los males.

Comment: Gracias, ya pude comprender lo que hice mal y entender mejor Angular